# Blender Unwraps, making sure things are the right way up

Tags: texturing, uv

Quick question,

Is there a quick way to make sure objects are the right way up when unwrapped? For instance;

[image]

I want the middle of the dials to unwrap the right way up, if that makes sense? So if I write something on the texture later it's the right way up to? At the moment the vertex at the top of the unwrapped dial on the right is actually midway around the right hand side on the mesh.

Sorry if I'm terrible at explaining things haha

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean right way up? Like facing outwards? Right way up in terms of world-space orientation? facing the same way relative to the object they're attached to? In any case, you can always just unwrap the object and then manually reorient the shells to how you want them to be. Once you've unwrapped the object the shells aren't going to reorient themselves and get misaligned from the text you put on the mesh.

Comment: Right way as in 12 o'clock on the model is 12 o'clock on the unwrap. At the moment I just manually make sure everything is in the right direction. :) It works well enough its just a little fiddly.

Comment: I'm a little late to the convo, but you should look into the TexTools addon, i honestly feel like it's a must have for UV unwrapping. But I'm pretty sure it has an "Align to world space" function built in.

Comment: Thank you so much! :) So far I've been manually rotating stuff, but that sounds much better.